# AspNetCoreModule Not Appearing in Modules list for website in IIS, even after installing Windows Hosting Bundle

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to run a .Net Core 2.1 Website through IIS. I had to reinstall IIS recently and was getting the error when navigating to my website:

> Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModule" in its module
> list

So I downloaded and installed the Windows Hosting Bundle for the relevant version of .Net Core from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.1

I then restarted IIS but I am getting the same error.

I noticed in the IIS Modules page for the ASP.Net Core Website I am trying to run, there is still no AspNetCoreModule listed. I take it it should be appearing here after installation of the bundle?

Any ideas what could prevent the installer adding this module?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if the AspNetCoreModule is not installed properly in IIS on the computer that is running the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Server components. To resolve this issue, open Programs and Features in Control Panel and check whether Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting is installed. If it is installed, repair it from Programs and Features, by selecting it, choosing Change, and then choosing Repair.

I also noticed that the SDK downloaded in the link you provided has x64 and x86. please check if you had downloaded the correct version.